# SQL statement producing data I do not want

Tags: android, sqlite

I am currently trying to retrieve some data from my SQLite Database on Android Studio but I am having issues trying to retrieve the data I need and I would much appreciate it if someone could take some time to help out. I currently have everything setup on SQL Fiddle if someone would like to help. I have also created a private chat room to chat live to fix the problem faster.

For anyone who would not like to join the chat room but wants to use SQL Fiddle, what I am trying to do is 2 things. Please look at the Database Schema while reading below.

1. I am trying to retrieve an expense and the peoples names involved in that expense. It is confusing me as from 1 to 3 people can be involved in the expense. I am displaying each Expense in a ListView and want to show the people involved names after the expense name and amount. But I am retrieving the expense name and amount a number of times based on the amount of people involved. Sample output of ListView.

   ```
   Rent     | 480 | Tim, Bob, Joe
   Takeaway |  20 | Tim, Joe
   Damages  |  50 | Bob, Joe
   ```

As you can see the data I am trying to retrieve is not always going to be the same.

2. I have an activity where I display the name of each person and the total amount of money that they own, but just imagine that we only have one expenses for example, when displaying how much each person owes, it shows

   ```
   Tim: 480
   Bob: 480
   Joe: 480
   ```

When they should be split to 160, 160, 160. Hope I make sense. So there is 2 SQL statements there, one for each of the requirements mentioned above. SQL Fiddle contains my attempt at the SQL statement for the first thing.

SQL Fiddle Link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/392431/1

Chat Room Link : https://us21.chatzy.com/62202633307431

Answer (score -1):

This is for SQL-Server.

```
SELECT e.*
    , p.name
    , CAST(e.amount/COUNT(p.pid) OVER (PARTITION BY e.eid) AS MONEY) AS EachPerson
FROM peoplexpenses pe
INNER JOIN people p
    ON pe.pid = p.pid
INNER JOIN expenses e 
    ON pe.eid = e.eid
```

Please don't use TEXT data type every where. In case in future you need GROUP BY name or month, it won't work.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (PARTITION BY e.eid) AS MONEY) AS EachPerson FROM peoplexpenses pe INNER JO' at line 1 - getting this error on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I already said it works for SQL Server not for MySQL. Please remove the tag in your question. Thanks.